# git difftool works for one repository, not for other

Tags: git, git-diff

Under my git home directory, I have two different git repositories (from two different projects) cloned.

so I have

```
/home/my_git_home/project1 (pointing to a different server/project)
/home/my_git_home/project2 (pointing to a different server/project)
```

My git config is as below :

```
diff.tool=tkdiff
user.name=xxxx
user.email=xxxxx
difftool.prompt=false
merge.tool=tkdiff
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
...
```

Now if I do a git difftool from /home/my_git_home/project1 I get a proper diff tool (tkdiff) UI.

However if I do from /home/my_git_home/project2, then I get command line diff being presented with following command

```
diff --cc /file/path/filename.java
index c03cd8b,fa745f1..0000000
--- a/file/path/filename.java
+++ b/file/path/filename.java
```

Any idea, what could have messed up for my project2?

Comment: it drove me nuts! Hit exact same problem! Custom "git difftool" was working for one project, but just spit the plain-old "diff" output on another project. The problem was that "git status" was showing "Your branch and 'origin/release' have diverged" along with list of "unmerged paths".. as soon as you get rid of those your "git difftool" will be back on track ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was seeing this behaviour in project2, after running

```
git pull origin master
```

The pull from master brought in merge conflict which I resolved.

At this stage git diff was using diff -cc command.

I did a git commit -a and after that, i can see any new changes view difftool properly